# Laravel MongoDb WhereMonth/WhereYear return empty

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I m trying to filter my document on created_at with whereMonth/whereYear clauses. But it always returns empty collection. I can't understand why.

Example :

```
$collection = MyModel::whereMonth('created_at', '06')->get();
```

I tried to change type of parameter with '6' or (int) 6... but nothing changed.

Someone to explain me why it doesn't work as documentation says (jenssegers package or laravel).
I didn't found any solution...

Thank you.

Comment: Show an example row from your table.

Comment: ```{
  "_id": { "$oid": "629b2eed7ecfb55f8c06cd0a" },"type": "FPRT",
  "number": "FPRTXXXXX",
  "date": "04-06-22",
  },
  "updated_at": { "$date": "2022-06-04T10:07:41.818Z" },
  "created_at": { "$date": "2022-06-04T10:07:41.818Z" }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure `->whereDate()` can understand this format `2022-06-04T10:07:41.818Z`. I would try reformatting the date to `mm/dd/yyyy` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found solution. I made my query in a whereRaw and used this :

```
$month = (int) $request->month;    
$queryMonth = [
   '$expr' => [
       '$eq' => [['$month' => '$created_at'], $month],
    ]];
$collection = Model::whereRaw($queryMonth)->get();
```

Same for requesting "year".

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = MyModel::all();

foreach($collection as $result)
{
$datetime = $result->created_at;

$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime);
$month = $date->month;
if($month == '06')
{
$collection = MyModel::whereMonth('created_at', $month)->get();
}
}
```

Comment: My request is number of the month. I need all documents created in June so i have ```$request->month = "06"; ```
In your case, Carbon is useless i guess.

Comment: Carbon makes date formatting easier. I edited my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work. Formatting created_at is useless,  is the same query at the end... it still returns empty :/